# Avoid namespace for nested member xml serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Please, is any convenience way to avoid namespace attributes for nested member **Request** when serializing **ResponseMessageEnvelope** class? Result xml will not be used for deserialization.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(AuthenticateRequest))]    
[XmlRoot("REQUEST",Namespace="")]
public abstract class BaseRequest
{
 ...
}

[XmlRoot("REQUEST", Namespace = "")]
public class AuthenticateRequest : BaseRequest
{
 ...
}

[XmlRoot("EXTSYSTEM", Namespace="")]
public class ResponseMessageEnvelope
{        
    public ResponseMessageEnvelope(BaseRequest request, BaseReponse response)
    {
        Request = request;
        Response = response;
    }

    [XmlElement("REQUEST", Namespace = "")]        
    public Request.BaseRequest Request
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        using (XmlWriter sWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true ,Indent = true }))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseMessageEnvelope));
            serializer.Serialize(sWriter, this, ns);                
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }    
}
```

I tried empty namespace for XmlRoot attribute on base and derived class, also for XmlElement on member but without success. Thanks for advice.

```
<EXTSYSTEM>
  <REQUEST xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p2:type="AuthenticateRequest">
  ...        
  </REQUEST>
....
</EXTSYSTEM>
```

This I would like to have:

```
<EXTSYSTEM>
  <REQUEST>
  ...        
  </REQUEST>
....
</EXTSYSTEM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class property must be decorated with the know types to avoid those declarations in the output. Change the request attribute inside ResponseMessageEnvelope to

```
[XmlElement("REQUEST")]
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(AuthenticateRequest))]
public Request.BaseRequest Request
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Also Namespace = "" is not needed at the element/root level

Comment: Yes, it's working fine for case that there is only one derived class (AuthenticateRequest ) but I have more like BetRequest, ResultRequest .... and all of them have to be serialised as REQUEST in default namespace. I can have same element names but different namespaces (several ELEMENT attributes like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455786/how-to-serialize-class-hierarchies-whose-classes-refer-to-each-to-other-but-avo) or different element name in one namespace (XmlInclude attribute). It give sense for deserialisation process. So thanks accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve problem by [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx):

```
[Serializable()]   
public abstract class BaseRequest
{
...
}

[XmlRoot("EXTSYSTEM", Namespace="")]
public class ResponseMessageEnvelope
{

    [XmlElement("REQUEST")]
    public Request.BaseRequest Request
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();           

        XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attr.ElementName = "REQUEST";
        attr.Type = this.Request.GetType();
        attr.Namespace = "";
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);

        attrOverrides.Add(typeof(ResponseMessageEnvelope), "Request", attrs);

        using (XmlWriter sWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true ,Indent = true }))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseMessageEnvelope), attrOverrides);
            serializer.Serialize(sWriter, this, ns);                
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```